# How to create a table column selector interface in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a user interface and functionality similar to the provided image in my project using react-js and material UI. When the user add something from the LHS box to the RHS box, the columns of the below table will change accordingly.

I want a custom solution or a 3rd party plugin. This UI is similar to the task list table with option in Redmine.

[Table Column Selector UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfnhR.png)

I have tried creating custom on but ended up with lots of issues.

Comment: I'm afraid asking for plugin recommendations if off topic for this site, and this is currently far too broad for us to help with a custom solution. If you have made an attempt yourself and are stuck on a single issue, you could post that here (with a [mre] and an explanation) and we may be able to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.